# BeautifulSoup. Проблема с обратными слэшами

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Помогите, пожалуйста. Пытаюсь получить фрагмент html-кода с помощью BS4.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://....')    
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
scr = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('matchesData'))

In[3]: scr
Out[3]:     
<script>
    var matchesData = JSON.parse('\x7B\x22goals\x22\x3A\x223\x22,\x22shots\x22\x3A\x229\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x221.575218915939331\x22,\x22time\x22\x3A\x2278\x22,\x22position\x22\x3A\x22FW\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20City\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Huddersfield\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x226\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222018\x2D08\x2D19\x22,\x22id\x22\x3A\x229213\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222018\x22,\x22roster_id\x22\x3A\x22243267\x22,\x22xA\x22\x3A\x220.02834254689514637\x22,\x22assists\x22\x3A\x220\x22,\x22key_passes\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22npg\x22\x3A\x223\x22,\x22npxG\x22\x3A\x221.575218915939331\x22,\x22xGChain\x22\x3A\x221.6953424215316772\x22,\x22xGBuildup\x22\x3A\x220.16331255435943604\x22\x7D');
</script>
```

При попытке получения содержимого тега, получаю строку с двойными обратными слэшами.

```
In[4]: scr.text
Out[4]: "\n\tvar matchesData\t= JSON.parse('\\x7B\\x22goals\\x22\\x3A\\x223\\x22,\\x22shots\\x22\\x3A\\x229\\x22,\\x22xG\\x22\\x3A\\x221.575218915939331\\x22,\\x22time\\x22\\x3A\\x2278\\x22,\\x22position\\x22\\x3A\\x22FW\\x22,\\x22h_team\\x22\\x3A\\x22Manchester\\x20City\\x22,\\x22a_team\\x22\\x3A\\x22Huddersfield\\x22,\\x22h_goals\\x22\\x3A\\x226\\x22,\\x22a_goals\\x22\\x3A\\x221\\x22,\\x22date\\x22\\x3A\\x222018\\x2D08\\x2D19\\x22,\\x22id\\x22\\x3A\\x229213\\x22,\\x22season\\x22\\x3A\\x222018\\x22,\\x22roster_id\\x22\\x3A\\x22243267\\x22,\\x22xA\\x22\\x3A\\x220.02834254689514637\\x22,\\x22assists\\x22\\x3A\\x220\\x22,\\x22key_passes\\x22\\x3A\\x221\\x22,\\x22npg\\x22\\x3A\\x223\\x22,\\x22npxG\\x22\\x3A\\x221.575218915939331\\x22,\\x22xGChain\\x22\\x3A\\x221.6953424215316772\\x22,\\x22xGBuildup\\x22\\x3A\\x220.16331255435943604\\x22\\x7D');\n"
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы получить строку с одинарными слэшами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Примечание:**

*Ответ на ваш запрос вам я уже дал* - см. мой [другой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/871695/233990).

**Этот ответ *не на то, что вы спрашивали*, но на то, что вы вероятно *хотели спросить***.

См.

- [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/233990)
- [Проблема X-Y](http://7bloggers.ru/xy-problem/).)

**И так, я в первую очередь попробую *переформулировать ваш вопрос:***

> ```
> Как в строке заменить всякую *четвёркy* знаков \xhh, где hh - двуместное
> шестнадцатеричное число, *одним* символом, именно тем, который соответствует 
> этому шестнадцатеричному числу в таблице ASCII? 
>
> В записе Питона, нужно например из части строки "\\x7A" (четыре символа) 
> сделать "\x7A" (один символ)? 
>
> ("\x7A" тот-же самое, что "z").
> ```

Это возможно сделать например с использованием факта, что в `re.sub()` может быть  в качестве *параметра для заменяющей строки* даже *функция*.

Эта функция автоматически вызывается для всякого совпадения с образцом, причём она принимает как параметр соответствующий объект типа `Matcher`):

```
import re

PATTERN = re.compile(r'\\x[0-9A-F]{2}')

def hex_to_ascii(matchobj):
    str = matchobj.group(0)
    if PATTERN.match(str, 0, 4):
        return chr(int(str[2:], 16))
    return None

def interpret(str):
    return PATTERN.sub(hex_to_ascii, str)
```

Теперь, когда вы вызовете функцию `interpret()` с той-же самой строкой `scr.text`, как в вашем вопросе, вы получите:

> ```
> In[1]: interpret(s)
> Out[1]: '\n\tvar matchesData\t= JSON.parse(\'{"goals":"3","shots":"9","xG":"1.575218915939331","time":"78","position":"FW","h_team":"Manchester City","a_team":"Huddersfield","h_goals":"6","a_goals":"1","date":"2018-08-19","id":"9213","season":"2018","roster_id":"243267","xA":"0.02834254689514637","assists":"0","key_passes":"1","npg":"3","npxG":"1.575218915939331","xGChain":"1.6953424215316772","xGBuildup":"0.16331255435943604"}\');\n'
> In[2]: print(interpret(s))
>
>   var matchesData = JSON.parse('{"goals":"3","shots":"9","xG":"1.575218915939331","time":"78","position":"FW","h_team":"Manchester City","a_team":"Huddersfield","h_goals":"6","a_goals":"1","date":"2018-08-19","id":"9213","season":"2018","roster_id":"243267","xA":"0.02834254689514637","assists":"0","key_passes":"1","npg":"3","npxG":"1.575218915939331","xGChain":"1.6953424215316772","xGBuildup":"0.16331255435943604"}');
>
> In[3]:
> ```

Comment: Мне нужно получить оригинальную строку, которую уже буду декодировать с помощью модуля json.

Comment: **Оригинальная строка - это только поток *байтов*, которые вы получили из сервера.** Вы получили такой поток: `...\x7B\x22goals...`, что в Питоне записывают как `'...\\x7B\\x22goals...'`. Когда бы на сервере было вместо того `...{"goals...` - семантически одинаковый, но по байтам другой - вы бы получили этой поток, который в Питоне записывают как `...{"goals...` - но вы к сожалению такой не получили. Потому моя функция `interpret()`. Ничто вам не мешает применить на результат из ней (на его соответственную часть) методы модула `json`.

Answer (score 1):

**Примечание:**

Мой ответ правилен - именно, что *нельзя сделать то, что вы спрашиваете* - хотя я подозреваю вас, что вы хотели спросить что-то другое.

См. также [мой другой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/871742/233990), и тоже

- [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/233990)
- [Проблема X-Y](http://7bloggers.ru/xy-problem/).

---

Ваша строка уже *есть* строкой с одинарными слэшами, так как символ `\\` в строке значит `\` (см. вторую строку последующей таблицы). Когда бы вы получили

```
....\x7B\x22goals...
```

то это бы выла совсем другая строка, так как `\x78` просто символ `x` и `\x22` просто симбол `"` - см. последнюю строку в таблице в [String literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html):

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Escape Sequence   |               Meaning                |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------+
| \newline          | Ignored                              |
| \\                | Backslash (\)                        |
| \'                | Single quote (')                     |
| \"                | Double quote (")                     |
| \a                | ASCII Bell (BEL)                     |
| \b                | ASCII Backspace (BS)                 |
| \f                | ASCII Formfeed (FF)                  |
| \n                | ASCII Linefeed (LF)                  |
| \r                | ASCII Carriage Return (CR)           |
| \t                | ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB)           |
| \v                | ASCII Vertical Tab (VT)              |
| \ooo              | ASCII character with octal value ooo |
| \xhh...           | ASCII character with hex value hh... |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

или попробуйте в интерпретаторе Питона:

> ```
> In[1]: "\x7B"
> Out[1]: '{'
> In[2]: "\x22"
> Out[2]: '"'
> ```

Дело в том, что `\x` значит, что этот символ вместе с последующее 2 шестнадцатеричными цифры будет интерпретирован как *один* знак (с ASCII значением шестнадцатеричного числа из этих двух цифр - см. [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/), из которой я выбираю (читайте второй и последний столбец):

```
+-----+----+-----+--------+-----+
| Dec | Hx | Oct |  Html  | Chr |
+-----+----+-----+--------+-----+
|  34 | 22 | 042 | &#34;  | "   |
| ... | .. | ... | .....  | ... |
| 123 | 7B | 173 | &#123; | {   |
+-----+----+-----+--------+-----+
```

Когда вы используете функцию `print()` для вывода вашей строки:

```
print(scr.text)
```

вы получите

> ```
> var matchesData   = JSON.parse('\x7B\x22goals\x22\x3A\x223\x22,\x22shots\x22\x3A\x229\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x221.575218915939331\x22,\x22time\x22\x3A\x2278\x22,\x22position\x22\x3A\x22FW\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20City\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Huddersfield\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x226\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222018\x2D08\x2D19\x22,\x22id\x22\x3A\x229213\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222018\x22,\x22roster_id\x22\x3A\x22243267\x22,\x22xA\x22\x3A\x220.02834254689514637\x22,\x22assists\x22\x3A\x220\x22,\x22key_passes\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22npg\x22\x3A\x223\x22,\x22npxG\x22\x3A\x221.575218915939331\x22,\x22xGChain\x22\x3A\x221.6953424215316772\x22,\x22xGBuildup\x22\x3A\x220.16331255435943604\x22\x7D');
> ```

Comment: Вот я и говорю, что scr.text делает из строки другую строку, где \x22 уже не является кавычками, а являеися четырьмя символами \x22